# URI Search fails with parse_exception when query string contains slash

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I get an error message when including a slash in query string.

The query is looks as below ,

```
"query_string": {
         "query": "usr0\\/7\\/0\\/20",
           "default_field": "logmsg"
           "analyzer": "keyword"
   }
```

my document looks like as below,

```
{
 "_index" : "logstash-log-2016.11.03",
   "_type" : "log",
  "_id" : "AVgpFuqyvHnB4OYqM9QE",
  "_score" : 2.2499034,
  "_source" : {
    "message" : "#<SNMP::SNMP_Trap:0x5383e289 @request_id=63766, @error_index=0, @error_status=0,  @value=#<SNMP::TimeTicks:0x3cbfc0fd @value=2033549672>>,blablabla>",
    "@timestamp" : "2016-11-03T07:28:37.177Z",
    "type" : "usrinfo",
    "logmsg" : "DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance:235 days, 08:44:56.72,SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID:IF-MIB::linkUp,IF-MIB::ifIndex.132:132,IF-MIB::ifDescr.132:usr0/7/0/20,IF-MIB::ifType.132:6,CISCO-IF-EXTENSION-MIB::cieIfStateChangeReason.132:up",
   "error_status" : "0",
}
```

I want to get documents that logmsg have the keyword "usr0/7/0/20",
but get no hits return

This occurs with ES  "number" : "2.3.5",

Answer (score 0):

The backslash escapes the forward slash, but you also need to escape the backslash itself, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "user0\\/0\\/0\\/2",
      "default_field": "name"
    }
  }
}
```

However, this will not work if your goal is to search for the token `user0/0/0/2` in your message field. You either need to use a `term` query or add `"analyzer": "keyword"` to your `query_string` query, otherwise `user0/0/0/2` will get tokenized to `user0`, `0`and `2`

Comment: hi Val, i have set query_string as you said and update my question,but when add "analyzer": "keyword" ,no error but no hists

Comment: But no parsing exception, which is the purpose of your initial question ;-)

Comment: If you want to make it work, you'll need to explain in more details what you're trying to achieve. You need to update your question with a sample document you're trying to match and the mapping you have.

Comment: hi Val, i have add my document in my question

Comment: What is the mapping of your `logmsg` field?

Comment: "logmsg " : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fielddata" : {
              "format" : "disabled"
            },
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                "ignore_above" : 4096
              }
            }
          }

Comment: Ok, in this case you'll not be able to match `user0/0/0/2` since `logmsg` is analyzed. You need to match that part in a logstash grok filter and store it in another `not_analyzed` string field

Comment: hi Val, I have try to use logmsg.raw field that not_analyzed, but still get no results

Comment: Are you sure you have one such raw field? If yes, then you can try to use a regexp query, but that's not optimal. The best is to use the grok approach I told you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127350/discussion-between-user6556472-and-val).